# MySQL Query - Extract numbers preceded by specific characters from a Text type field

Tags: mysql

In one of MySQL data base table I have a column which contains values in Text format. Lets say the column name is '`test_column`' and table name is '`test_table`'. One of the field/cell value is as given below.

```
---
abc: 1
pqr: 1
uvw: 0
opq: 5
srt: 6
xyz: 1
qrs: 1
ijk: 1
tuv: 1
ghi: 1
---
```

So, I want to take all those numbers and get the `sum` of all. There is a unique format for the values, the numbers are preceded by a colon and a space (`': '`). So, how can I fetch those **numbers** and calculate the **sum** through a query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Better store every value in a seperate column or row...

Comment: Changing it seems to be a good idea but it will impact our system at-least for sometime which we cant afford..Also, we save the data in hash format in to a text field. So, I would like to see how I can extract the details in MySQL. Thanks anyway for your suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Rajesh has clarified the key-value pairs in the question are actually not in different rows, but they are all in the same row (with perhaps new line characters (`\n`) between the pairs).  Given this clarification, my original
answer was not useful to him.  Here I am giving an updated answer.  I think it is easier to process the string of multiple key-value pair outside of MySQL and use a high-level program language to process it.  Below I show an example
using Java.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SplitAndSumKvPairs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = ""
                + "abc: 1\n"
                + "pqr: 1\n"
                + "uvw: 0\n"
                + "opq: 5\n"
                + "srt: 6\n"
                + "xyz: 1\n"
                + "qrs: 1\n"
                + "ijk: 1\n"
                + "tuv: 1\n"
                + "ghi: 1";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?<key>\\w+):\\s*(?<value>\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        int sum = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(m.group("value"));
            sum += value;
        }

        System.out.format("Given this input %s%n%nthe sum is %d", input, sum);
    }

}
```

The output of this program was:

```
Given this input abc: 1
pqr: 1
uvw: 0
opq: 5
srt: 6
xyz: 1
qrs: 1
ijk: 1
tuv: 1
ghi: 1

the sum is 18
```

Alternatively, one may try to use a stored function or stored procedure to express a similar logic as above.

**Old answer assuming the key-value pairs are in different rows**

```
select    
    sum(substring_index(test_column, ': ', -1)) 
from
    test_table
```

The code has been tested in SqlFiddle ([click on this link to see it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/142b09/1))

```
create table test_table (
    id              int not null primary key auto_increment
    , test_column   varchar(20) not null
) engine=innoDB;

insert into test_table
values
(null, 'abc: 1')
, (null, 'pqr: 1')
, (null, 'uvw: 0')
, (null, 'opq: 5')
, (null, 'srt: 6')
, (null, 'xyz: 1')
, (null, 'qrs: 1')
, (null, 'ijk: 1')
, (null, 'tuv: 1')
, (null, 'ghi: 1');
```

The answer was

```
18
```

Comment: What was the error message?  I tried my code on SqlFiddle.com.  I updated my answer above to show the result.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you for your efforts. But I guess you have misunderstood the question. Single field contains the above value  and it is not the field values of consecutive rows....

Comment: Okay. In your example, the single text field has 10 key-value pairs.  In your actual data, is there always 10 pairs?  Or this number varies in different rows?

Comment: No there can be 10 or less or more than that. It varies. Also, the preceding label need not be of 3 character length...

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer to recognize that the multiple key-value pairs are in the same row (not multiple rows)